# How do I COUNT and FILTER? (Wikidata query)

Tags: sparql, wikidata

On [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/), 
I am trying to filter events of certain time periods, but I get errors, or count of 0, or I get the same count no matter how I change the time period.
What am I doing wrong?

```sql
SELECT (count(distinct ?event) as ?cnt)    
WHERE
{
?event wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q171558.

OPTIONAL {
?event rdfs:label ?eventLabel.

FILTER ( ?date >= "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date && ?date <= "2018-12-31"^^xsd:date )  
}.

}
```

I also see an example from the query page, but how do I count? What should I do to the first line of the query to convert it into Count without causing an error? :

```sql
SELECT ?event ?eventLabel ?date    
WHERE
{
    ?event wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1190554.

    OPTIONAL { ?event wdt:P585 ?date. }     
    OPTIONAL { ?event wdt:P580 ?date. }

    FILTER(BOUND(?date) && DATATYPE(?date) = xsd:dateTime).     
    BIND(NOW() - ?date AS ?distance).

    FILTER(0 <= ?distance && ?distance < 31).

    OPTIONAL {
        ?event rdfs:label ?eventLabel.
        FILTER(LANG(?eventLabel) = "en").
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first query doesn't make sense given that the variable `?date` in the filter isn't bound to anything outside of the FILTER ...

Comment: If you want to count something, you have to use an aggregate function. This aggregate function is applied to groups and if no grouping is defined it will be applied to all resources. That said, anything else you use in the projection (aka SELECT ... part) has to be an aggregate as well as long as you don't use it to define the groups (via `group by ...`). For your second query, I do not know what you want to achieve, so it's impossible to answer. What is the purpose of the second query? Is it done by yourself? What do you expect as result when counting?

Comment: Well, I want to count the number of events of certain time period, and whose label is in certain language. But I think I fixed the problems... so it's fine now. Just that sparql still confuses me. The second part is an example I found on the query page which queries events in certain language. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, my solution was to replace the first line of the second query with SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?event) AS ?cnt)   And whoever organized my queries, thank you. I'm new to all these xD

Comment: So, I assume your second query is supposed to return the number of events in the last 31 days? Does this work? I'd think it will lead to a timeout most of the time

Comment: It does indeed. Worked ok with Limit 100. Now i'm working on dbpedia trying to figure out why I'm getting duplicates in result (on my new post), if you're interested I'll be happy :)

Comment: I don't see how the `LIMIT 100` should help for a query where you do `SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?event) AS ?cnt)` - I mean, `LIMIT` is used to reduce the number of returned "rows". But your query in fact return just a single number - so, what do expect does the `LIMIT` do in your query? I don't get it

Comment: I am a total beginner in sparkl but I used it not to time out? D= and I increased the distance (time period). Doesn't it give me what I need? Number of events whose label is in language A from a certain time period....

Comment: No, `LIMIT` is used to limit the number of returned results. For your query, you'll always get exactly one "row" with a single value that denotes the number of events. For other queries indeed, using a `LIMIT` can drastically reduce the runtime. imagine, for your query the engine has to compute **all events**. What should be limited here? Without a `count` of course, using something like `LIMIT 100` can stop searching once 100 results have been found. if you want to have the aggregation on a subset, the `LIMIT` has to be put in a subquery`

Comment: And I'm still getting a timeout, are we talking about the same query? You said your second query with just `SELECT (COUNT(...`: So I do `SELECT (count(distinct ?event) as ?cnt)    
WHERE
{
    ?event wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1190554.

    OPTIONAL { ?event wdt:P585 ?date. }     
    OPTIONAL { ?event wdt:P580 ?date. }

    FILTER(BOUND(?date) && DATATYPE(?date) = xsd:dateTime).     
    BIND(NOW() - ?date AS ?distance).

    FILTER(0 <= ?distance && ?distance < 31).

   
}
limit 100` - it always leads to a timeout